# Spring Data Neo4j 5 - HttpMessageNotWritableException when hitting resource endpoints

Tags: scala, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-ogm, spring-data-neo4j-5

In an attempt to recreate the [Spring Data Neo4j official Movies example](https://github.com/neo4j-examples/movies-java-spring-data-neo4j) in Scala I have ran into an issue jsonifying on the Spring Data Neo4j layer.

The details are noted in the `README` in this [example project](https://github.com/skyferthesly/movies-scala-spring-data-neo4j).

Booting the Spring app and hitting `/movies/<id>` gives the following stacktrace:

> 018-03-27 15:33:23 WARN  DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver:442 - Failed
>   to write HTTP message:
>   org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException:
>   Could not write JSON: Invalid Object Id definition for movies.Movie:
>   cannot find property with name 'id'; nested exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Invalid Object Id
>   definition for movies.Movie: cannot find property with name 'id'
>   (through reference chain:
>   org.springframework.hateoas.PagedResources["_embedded"]->java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap["movies"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])

I have opened an official Spring Data Neo4j JIRA issue [here.](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAGRAPH-1074)

**Edit:** After the latest comment, I have removed unrelated theories about the root cause from this post. And I have updated the example project to expose the IDs on the `Spring Data Rest` layer using a `PostConstruct` method (thanks @meistermeier). I also tried the `RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter` method. However, the original `HttpMessageNotWritableException` persists. Any ideas?

**Update:**
Modeling `Movie.scala` after [SDN-University example](https://github.com/neo4j-examples/sdn-university/blob/master/src/main/java/school/domain/Student.java), I tried using `com.voodoodyne.jackson.jsog.JSOGGenerator` as an Object ID Generator. I can successfully hit `/movies/` but the only key is "id", and it's simply an index, and not the actual id. However, 38 movies do return, the amount in the Movies data set. I would think this narrows down the issue to the jsonfying part.

**Update 2:**
By using a bandaid to manually form the `json` in the controller (using an `object-to-map` function, and a `map-to-json` function) I am finally able to send data out through the endpoints. I have updated the example project to demonstrate this. I can successfully retrieve objects from the `movieRepository`, and manipulate them as I please. I think this has clearly narrowed down the problem to the jsonification. Does anyone have a clear example (Java or Scala) on how to properly annotate `NodeEntity` with `JsonIdentifyInfo`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after more than a month I have solved the problem.

You must add `scala.beans.BeanProperty` to any `vars` that need generated getters and setters.

Added this to my `NodeEntity` properties as well as on the `sessionFactory` bean and the `transactionManager` bean, and all my problems magically vanished.

It would make sense to document this *required* annotation to use these libraries in Scala.

Answer (score 1):

First a note on the id as `String` part: The internal Neo4j id has to be of type `Long` (paragraph between the info sections here: https://neo4j.com/docs/ogm-manual/current/reference/#reference:annotating-entities:entity-identifier). With another type than `Long` Neo4j OGM is unable to find the, so called, native id field on your class.

Now back to the initial problem you are facing.
Spring Data Rest suppresses the exposure of id-like fields and Spring Data Neo4j will mark/register fields with an `@Id` annotation as such.
To use this id fields you could for example do something like this:

```
public class SpringBootApplication {
  private final RepositoryRestConfiguration configuration;

  public SpringBootApplication(RepositoryRestConfiguration configuration) {
    this.configuration=configuration;
  }

  @PostConstruct
  public void configuration() {
    configuration.exposeIdsFor(Person.class);
  }
```

I know that this is Java, so this but more Scala-ish.

Side notes:

- We are currently upgrading the movie sample
- This problem is totally unrelated to the class loading bug

Comment: Thank you for your response. I thought I had issues implementing the `PostConstruct`, but the issue was a bad java-to-scala translation on my part. So, I have implemented the `PostConstruct`, and I am getting the original `org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException` error. I will update the main post.